# How to remove #NUM! from calculation and return zero value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating a contract inventory file with inputs for all contracts. I have 2 columns, one for start date & another for end date. And a seperate cell which indicated today's date using `=TODAY()`.

I would like to calculate the balance years, months and days in one of the cells. This is the formula i used to indicate that.

`=IF(DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"y")=0,"",DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"y")&" years, ")&IF(DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"ym")=0,"",DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"ym")&" months, ")&IF(DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"md")=0,"",DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"md")&" days")`

But when the end date is before today's date, it always shows `#NUM!`, any chance to show as zero instead of error when the contract had expired ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the entire formula with `IFERROR`, so it will read like this

`=IFERROR(IF(DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"y")=0,"",DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"y")&" years, ")&IF(DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"ym")=0,"",DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"ym")&" months, ")&IF(DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"md")=0,"",DATEDIF($B$3,H8,"md")&" days"), 0)`

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Another question is there any way the formula can spot an error in the end date? Let's say 28/02/19, but the user key in 30/02/19. Anyway the excel can spot there is no such day in the calendar?

Comment: @Brandon you can open new question for that, but try google a bit for Data Validation Excel